# Use the same Entity in multiple DbContext (EF Core 2)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have two DbContext (EFCore 2) in one project that are sharing the same entity.
my problem is that EFCore creates two tables for that entity.

each DbContext has its own schema. in fact, i want create a multi domain (and multi DbContext) app but entities in one DbContext are shared and other DbContexts reference those entities.

Contexts:

```
public class CommonContext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("common");
    }

    public DbSet<DomainModel.Common.User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class App1DbContext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("app1");
    }

    public DbSet<DomainModel.App1.Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Models:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Book 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }
}
```

I first created common schema by using migrations:

```
add-migration -context CommonContext
update-database -context CommonContext
```

then, i created app1 schema:

```
add-migration -context app1
update-database -context app1
```

but EF created "Users" table in both schemas! EF doesn't understand that these two separate DbContext are sharing the same entity(User). i expect that EF creates User table in only Common schema (CommonContext).

how can i fix this problem?

Comment: public User Author { get; set; }

Here u use author as navigation property of the user And add book table as a property of App1DbContext, So obviously EF core create two separate user table for two separate schemas. 

As I know the solution to this scenario is not possible using this approach.

Comment: Your app1 schema is referencing an object User, so of course its going to create a second table.  <schema>.<table> is not the same as <schema2>.<table>  I don't think you can get there with code-first.

Comment: thank you, i think so. i have two separate DbContexts and i cannot share entities between them. their corresponding databases may be located in different servers!

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution for this? I'm currently dealing with this same exact issue and don't know how to fix